# OpenWRT - Allow Internet only between LAN <> WAN / disallow lan can reach wan network

Tags: openwrt

I need to configure a OpenWRT-Router ( TP-Link WR1043ND v1.2 ) to create a separate network with internet access only.

I cant figure out how to allow just internet, or, disallow device recognizing from LAN > to > WAN.

If I connect a client to the LAN Ports of OpenWRT-Router, the Internet working and I can (unfortunately) reach the ISP-Router's network and all of his clients.

I dont want that OpenWRT´s LAN network can reach the ISP-Routers network. It is even possible on openwrt to archive that? When possible, how?

Comment: This is something that should be configured on the ISP router. However using iptables you could try something like 
`iptables -I zone_lan -d <subnet-of-isp-network> -j DROP`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to make your router be a switch only?  Can you draw diagrams of what you're trying to achieve?